# how to add simulations in a plot in Rshiny

Tags: shiny, reactive, ggplotly

I am trying to develop a Rshiny app to plot simulations (the increase in the amount of a toxic compound over time) in a graph using ggplotly.
I am using a reactive object to be able to add in the same graphic multiple simulations made by the user. All the predictions (dataframes) are kept in a list (List 1).
I have tried to bind the different lists of dataframes and give them and id in order to plot them. It works under non-reactive environment but not in reactive one. The main error that I get is "data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: 20, 0"

Any help would be highly appreciated!

```
     server <- function(input, output) {

     List1 <- reactiveVal(list())

     observeEvent(input$Add_prediction, {
    
    # to make new predictions with the Amount function
    new_pred<- data.frame(time, Amount(x=time, y=level))
          
    names(new_pred)<-c("time_pred", "level")
    
    new_list <- List1()
    new_list[[input$Name]] <- new_pred
    
    List1(new_list)
    
    })


      object <- List1()
      obj <- do.call(rbind, object)
    
      obj$id <- factor(rep(1:length(object), each = sapply(object, nrow)))
        
      ggplot() + 
        geom_line(aes(x = time_pred, y = concentration, colour = input$Name)) +
        xlab(input$xaxis) +
        ylab(input$yaxis) +
        theme_cowplot() +
        theme(legend.title = element_blank())
    
    ggplotly(object)
    
})
```

}

Comment: the plot part needs to be within a render function. something like `output$my_plot <- plotly::renderPlotly({ plot_code })`

Comment: Thanks for the help @AdroMine !! I tried to apply the render function but it still does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how the new predictions are getting created, I can't reproduce any errors on my side. But the app should be structured along the lines of:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton('Add_prediction', 'Add Prediction'), 
    # <<more input fields as required>>
    plotly::plotlyOutput('pred_plot')
)
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    List1 <- reactiveVal(list())
    
    observeEvent(input$Add_prediction, {
        
        # to make new predictions with the Amount function
        new_pred <- data.frame(time, Amount(x=time, y=level))
        
        names(new_pred)<-c("time_pred", "level")
        
        new_list <- List1()
        new_list[[input$Name]] <- new_pred
        
        List1(new_list)
        
    })
    
    # create plot 
    output$pred_plot <- plotly::renderPlotly({
        object <- List1()
        obj <- do.call(rbind, object)
        
        obj$id <- factor(rep(1:length(object), each = sapply(object, nrow)))
        
        plot <- ggplot() + 
            geom_line(aes(x = time_pred, y = concentration, colour = input$Name)) +
            xlab(input$xaxis) +
            ylab(input$yaxis) +
            theme_cowplot() +
            theme(legend.title = element_blank())

        # need to pass the ggplot output to ggplotly
        ggplotly(plot)
    })
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for trying to help me AdroMine! But I still get the error :( Every new prediction (new_pred) contains two variables (time and amount). Then I group each dataframe in a list. I think that the problem is more related to that the program does not recognize each dataframe from the list... The error that I get is "Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: 41, 0". Maybe I can access to each dataframe in the list with >%%>? but I'm not sure how to do it...

Comment: are you sure your `Amount` function is working correctly? The dataframe error seems to suggest that for line `data.frame(time, Amount(x=time, y=level))`,  `time` is of length 20, while the output of `Amount(x=time,y=level)` is of 0 rows

Comment: Yes, I tried and I have values for the same number of rows of both variables